# Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I imported a grails project using Intellij idea.  Now when i tried to run-app the project it shows the following error.

```
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration to continue.
```

**Note**  I am using grails 2.3.8 version.

--Stacktrace  results the following message

```
Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:317)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:513)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:774)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:768)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:673)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): repo.grails.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): repo.grails.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:437)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.grails.org
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:337)
    ... 18 more

Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1
Error |
Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration to continue.
```

Comment: What did it say when you used `--stacktrace` to see the full trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say `java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.grails.org` is the core issue. Do you need to configure a proxy? See the [docs for the add-proxy command](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.0.0/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html).

Comment: Link seems to be broken. I believe this is the latest for  [add-proxy 2.5.0 docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html)